# iPad connections to Cisco VPN error -- "Enter your user authentication"

Tags: vpn, cisco, apple, cisco-vpn, iphone

Is anyone else having problems with the iPad IPSec (Cisco) VPN configuration?

I've configured a Cisco VPN connection to a PIX 501 firewall on a 32GB Wifi Apple iPad.  This is done in Settings -> General -> Network -> VPN -> Add VPN Configuration -> IPSec tab.  When everything is set up properly and I attempt to connect I just get a popup that says "Enter your user authentication" with no fields to enter either piece of info, and just OK and Cancel buttons.

I've read about similar problems with the VPN client built into Mac OS X and the iPhone 3GS but never with the iPad.  Does anybody know a solution?  I'm not afraid to change the configuration of my PIX 501 if that's necessary.

Comment: I am having the same issue with a PIX 515.

Is the PIX to old and we need to upgrade o rjust update the software on the PIX?

Please let me know, did you upgrade and did it fix your issue?

Comment: I was never able to solve the problem and gave up on using the iPad with my PIX.

Comment: Here's hoping it magically works once the iOS 4.1 upgrade rolls out!

Answer (score 1):

I had problems connecting iPads to our VPN until upgrading the Cisco IOS. I was using an old 1710, rather than an ASA, but here's a mention from Cisco about the versions required:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/iPhone/2.0/connectivity/guide/iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with pix 515e version software 6.3. In order to use the iPad vpn client you need at least Pix version software 7.2.x .

http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7696973

Upgrading pix 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/pix/pix70/release/notes/pix704rn.html